Show that $\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$

Let be $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ where
$$
f(x,y):=\begin{cases} \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2},&(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\0,&(x,y)=(0,0).\end{cases}
$$
Show that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

My approach:
If $f$ was differentiable at $(0,0)$, by definition there must exist a unique matrix $A=(a,b)$ such that
\begin{align*}
&\lim\limits_{{x\choose y}\to{0\choose 0}}\frac{\left|\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}-0-A{x\choose y}\right|}{\Vert {x\choose y}\Vert_2}=0.
\end{align*}
We consider the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{n},0\right)$ which implies that
\begin{align*}
&\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left|\frac{\frac{1}{n^3}+0^3}{\frac{1}{n^2}+0^2}-0-A{\frac{1}{n}\choose 0}\right|}{\frac{1}{n}}=1-a\implies a=1.
\end{align*}
Similarly, $\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ implies
\begin{align*}
&\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left|\frac{\frac{1}{n^3}+0^3}{\frac{1}{n^2}+0^2}-0-A{0\choose \frac{1}{n}}\right|}{\frac{1}{n}}=1-b\implies b=1.
\end{align*}
Finally, we look at the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and see that
\begin{align*}
&\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left|\frac{\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^3}}{\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}}-0-A{\frac{1}{n}\choose \frac{1}{n}}\right|}{\sqrt{2}\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1-a-b).
\end{align*}
As we have already shown that $a=b=1$ it is not possible that the last limit attains $0$. So there doesn't exists a unique matrix $A$.

This apporach feels a bit lengthy but I was not able to produce a contradiction only by using one sequence. Maybe someone else has a swifter approach or can give me some feedback on this.

Can you please clarify whether the cube in the denominator of $f$ is a typo?

This looks good to me (after your correction), and I don't see any obvious way to simplify it.

I've edited my answer accordingly

There are minor  mistakes in your computations, though the spirit is right. In the first limit, you get $|1-a|$, and not $1-a$. The same problem happens in your second limit. You also have a couple typos in that $y$ in the denominator has power $3$ in the statement, but power $2$ in your computations. And the matrix size, usually in this context $A$ would be $1\times 2$ and not $2\times 1$.
(against policy, OP changed the question after answers had been posted). A marginally simpler approach is to note that $f$ is not continuous at zero, so it cannot be differentiable. Indeed, if you approach $(0,0)$ along the path $(x,0)$, the limit is zero. While if you approach along $(0,y)$, the limit is $1$.

I think the $y^3$ is a typo, judging from the computations afterwards.

There are two cubes and four squares in the question, so probabilistically you are right :D

:D Nothing goes over a probabilistic proof

Not sure if I understood your remarks correctly. The limits should be $|1-a|$ and $|1-b|$, I forgot the absolute value bars.

You are right, my bad.

@MartinArgerami The "new version" of $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ so you may want to remove or add some context to the last paragraph.

@PierreCarre: rather, OP should have not changed the question after having received answers.

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x,0) = 0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} f(0,y) = 1$ therefore the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$, hence it's not differentiable at $(0,0)$
Update
It seems the question was edited, which now has $f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ instead of $\displaystyle\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^3}$ (clarification so that other answers may not be misunderstood and downvoted)
An alternative way to prove a function is not differentiable at $\mathbf{x}$ (which is $(x,y)$) is to find some vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $\nabla_\mathbf{v} f(\mathbf{x}) \neq \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{v}$ where $\nabla f$ is the gradient and $\nabla_\mathbf{v} f(\mathbf{x})$ defined as
$$\nabla_\mathbf{v} f(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(\mathbf{x}+h\mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{x})}{h}$$
For our situation $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$, $\nabla f(\mathbf{0}) = (1,1)$. Let $\mathbf{v} = (1,1)$ then
$$\nabla_\mathbf{v} f(\mathbf{0}) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h,h) - f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{h}{h} = 1$$
which is clearly different from $\nabla f(\mathbf{\mathbf{0}})\cdot \mathbf{v} = 2$

@PierreCarre My bad. I've fixed it

I just want to point out that you do not need to wonder what matrix $A$ might be... In fact, you can start from $A = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)\right) = \left(1 \quad 1 \right)$ and analyse the limit that you mentioned: If it exists and is finite, the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$, otherwise it is not.
